# How to use python-barcode in Amazon AWS lambda (Python 3.8)?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, python-imaging-library, python-barcode

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/barcode/writer.py", line 9, in <module>
    import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

// etc etc

File "/var/task/barcode/base.py", line 80, in write
    output = self.render(options, text)
  File "/var/task/barcode/codex.py", line 255, in render
    return super().render(options, text)
  File "/var/task/barcode/base.py", line 100, in render
    return self.writer.render(code)
  File "/var/task/barcode/writer.py", line 269, in render
    self._callbacks["paint_text"](xpos, ypos)
  File "/var/task/barcode/writer.py", line 440, in _paint_text
    font = ImageFont.truetype(self.font_path, font_size)
  File "/var/task/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 791, in truetype
    return freetype(font)
  File "/var/task/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 788, in freetype
    return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
  File "/var/task/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 198, in __init__
    if core.HAVE_RAQM:
  File "/var/task/PIL/_util.py", line 19, in __getattr__
    raise self.ex
  File "/var/task/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 48, in <module>
    from . import _imagingft as core
ImportError: /lib64/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by Pillow.libs/libpng16-39c06ea1.so.16.40.0)
[ERROR] 2023-07-28T18:22:56.139Z d6ac4e4c-7517-45fc-a72e-47fe541f977a An error occurred running the application. Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/task/barcode/writer.py", line 9, in <module> import Image ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image' During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/task/mangum/protocols/http.py", line 58, in run await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send) File "/var/task/fastapi/applications.py", line 270, in __call__ await super().__call__(scope, receive, send) File "/var/task/starlette/applications.py", line 124, in __call__ await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send) File "/var/task/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__ raise exc File "/var/task/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__ await self.app(scope, receive, _send) File "/var/task/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 84, in __call__ await self.app(scope, receive, send) File "/var/task/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__ raise exc File "/var/task/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__ await self.app(scope, receive, sender) File "/var/task/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__ raise e File "/var/task/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__ await self.app(scope, receive, send) File "/var/task/starlette/routing.py", line 706, in __call__ await route.handle(scope, receive, send) File "/var/task/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle await self.app(scope, receive, send) File "/var/task/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app response = await func(request) File "/var/task/fastapi/routing.py", line 237, in app raw_response = await run_endpoint_function( File "/var/task/fastapi/routing.py", line 165, in run_endpoint_function return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values) File "/var/task/starlette/concurrency.py", line 41, in run_in_threadpool return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args) File "/var/task/anyio/to_thread.py", line 33, in run_sync return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread( File "/var/task/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 877, in run_sync_in_worker_thread return await future File "/var/task/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 807, in run result = context.run(func, *args) File "/var/task/app/app.py", line 210, in generate_pdf prescription_pdf(data, os.path.join('/tmp/', pdf_filename) ) File "/var/task/app/app.py", line 623, in prescription_pdf Code128(data['external_id'], writer=ImageWriter(format="PNG")).write(rv) File "/var/task/barcode/base.py", line 80, in write output = self.render(options, text) File "/var/task/barcode/codex.py", line 255, in render return super().render(options, text) File "/var/task/barcode/base.py", line 100, in render return self.writer.render(code) File "/var/task/barcode/writer.py", line 269, in render self._callbacks["paint_text"](xpos, ypos) File "/var/task/barcode/writer.py", line 440, in _paint_text font = ImageFont.truetype(self.font_path, font_size) File "/var/task/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 791, in truetype return freetype(font) File "/var/task/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 788, in freetype return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine) File "/var/task/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 198, in __init__ if core.HAVE_RAQM: File "/var/task/PIL/_util.py", line 19, in __getattr__ raise self.ex File "/var/task/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 48, in <module> from . import _imagingft as core ImportError: /lib64/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by Pillow.libs/libpng16-39c06ea1.so.16.40.0)
```

When trying to execute

```
Code128(someNumber, writer=ImageWriter(format="PNG")).write(rv)
```

The problem (I think) is that zlib 1.2.9 doesn't exist in AWS lambda. I've already tried to add the layer from [klayers](https://api.klayers.cloud/api/v2/p3.8/layers/latest/us-east-1/html) that adds PIL but I'm getting the same error.

If I upgrade to Python3.9 or Python3.10 I get different (worse) errors. I'd like this to work with Python 3.8.

Comment: Please click [edit] and add your [mcve]. It's no use showing an error message without showing the code that caused it. Thank you.